# Find frequency based off unique region

Tags: python, pandas, parsing

I have a dataframe with 324 regions, here is a screenshot for reference of the format:

[image]

I need to get the frequency of a certain species in each region.

So I need a systematic way that will loop through each region, take the total_observations numbers, and divide it by the sum of all total_observations in that region.

Using Afghanistan for an example as to what I want for each row in my dataframe... I want this to be the output for Afghanistan, but I need this to happen for every region.
[image]

Comment: please dont post pictures, try giving codes or minimal sample of the dataset. community doesn't endorse use of pictures here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this on a minimal dataframe I wrote and I think it should work in your case too.
Its a good use case for pandas .groupby() method.

```
freq = (df.groupby(["Region", "Species"]).sum() / df.groupby(["Region"]).sum())["total_observations"]
```